# Rewriting does not stop after matching a RewriteRule with the [L] flag

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the path `/health` to `/health.php`.

I currently have have the following `.htaccess` file, with a *catch-all* rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

So I just added a new rule before the catch-all:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^health$ health.php [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

But to my surprise, it doesn't rewrite to `health.php` when I request `/health` in the browser.

However, when I remove the last (catch-all) rule, it works as expected.

**Why doesn't mod_rewrite stop processing rules after matching a rule with the `[L]` flag?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it. I always thought that the `[L]` flag stopped the processing of all the rules, period. Actually, it just stops processing rules in the current ruleset, but then **re-runs the whole ruleset on the rewritten request**.

Hence, my catch-all code was finally catching it, as the [rewrite log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) shows:

```
strip per-dir prefix: [...]/public/health -> health
applying pattern '^health$' to uri 'health'
rewrite 'health' -> 'health.php'
add per-dir prefix: health.php -> [...]/public/health.php
strip document_root prefix: [...]/public/health.php -> /health.php
internal redirect with /health.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]

strip per-dir prefix: [...]/public/health.php -> health.php
applying pattern '^health$' to uri 'health.php'
strip per-dir prefix: [...]/public/health.php -> health.php
applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'health.php'
rewrite 'health.php' -> 'index.php'
add per-dir prefix: index.php -> [...]/public/index.php
strip document_root prefix: [...]/public/index.php -> /index.php
internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]

strip per-dir prefix: [...]/public/index.php -> index.php
applying pattern '^health$' to uri 'index.php'
strip per-dir prefix: [...]/public/index.php -> index.php
applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
rewrite 'index.php' -> 'index.php'
add per-dir prefix: index.php -> [...]/public/index.php
initial URL equal rewritten URL: [...]/public/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

The solution, found on [this blog](http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/ignoring-internal-rewrites-in-htaccess/), involves putting a conditional before the catch-all rule, to only execute it when no internal redirect has been processed before:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```